# Building OpenCV as a part of your project -Debug (F11) into OpenCV library

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.

I have build my project using the pre-build directory of OpenCV.
Afterwards I have built openCV using CMake and created the DLL and lib files for my project.

The thing is that I'd like to use openCV and as part of my project, consider commands as  debug into OpenCV's functions [inside open CV library].

At the begning I was using the DLL and LIB of OpenCV therefore I couldn't go inside functions taken from OpenCV

- I have tried to add  my project to the solution file created by CMake. I add some problems at this phase, since my project couldn't recognize the *.h files of the other projects from the solution (even when I have set my project as primary project of the solution file) .
- I have tried to include all the headers and cpp files into a new project - but it all looked like a big mess

I'd be glad to receive any solution for that

Cheers 
S

Answer (score 3):

You can debug into an external library.

In the project settings tab look for 'visual studio directories' in the 'source code' field include the path to the openCV sources.  Then make sure that the .pdb files for each of the debug dll are in the same directory as the dll.

OpenCV is mostly mature, but the documentation isn't perfect and you do often have to go into the source to find out which features are actually present and what assumptions they have meade

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I suggest to continue using OpenCV as an external library (`dll` and `lib`).

If you think that you need to debug code in OpenCV, then 99% that you are looking in the wrong place. OpenCV is a *mature library*, and while there are certainly still bugs there, they are very rare by now. Most likely the cause of bugs is due to incorrect usage. It would be much more efficient to check the documentation then to start trying to decipher someone else's code.

Comment: I'd not like to debug OpenCV library and look for bugs, I'm quite sure that OpenCV is mature library  ,  I'd like to follow OpenCV implementation on face detection algorithm and observe the implementation of the algorithm.